# Jetpack compose animation choppy changing views

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following view that was setup as  `if else`, but I'm trying to animate the view changing to have a subtle fade in\fade out between `SomeView()` and it's super janky and not very smooth. I looked at the documentation, but it's not clear to me if I can have a `if else` for a view that could animate between?

Is there a better way to do this?

```kotlin
                    Column {
                        donationItems.forEach { item ->
                            AnimatedVisibility(
                                item.productId == productIdSelected
                            ){
                                SomeView()
                            }
                            AnimatedVisibility(
                                item.productId != productIdSelected
                                ) {
                                SomeView2()
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compose animations within an if-else statement, it is advisable to use `AnimatedContent` instead of the `AnimatedVisibility`

You cannot directly incorporate the condition into the if-else statement because, for UI changes to occur, there must be a state change. Therefore, you should create a `MutableState` with a desired initial value and then pass it to `AnimatedContent`. Each time you need to animate to a different composable, you can change the value of this state.

```
var isProductSelected by remember{ mutableStateOf(false) }
Column {
    donationItems.forEach { item ->
        AnimatedContent(targetState = isProductSelected) {myState->
            if (myState == true ){ //  <-your condition
                SomeView()
            }else{
                SomeView2()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

make sure to use the value emitted by `AnimatedContent` for handling condition in if statement (`myState` in case of the code above)

For jank-free animations, choosing the appropriate animation API is crucial.
For jank-free animations, selecting the appropriate animation API is crucial. Refer to the official Android documentation on Compose animations to make an informed choice: [Choosing the right animation API](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/choose-api).

Comment: Thank you! This `{myState->` the component I was missing.